# Where to put jQuery code for DOM manipulation in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have some jQuery code that deals with DOM manipulation, simple stuff like fadeIn(), etc...

Is the best practice to put

```
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and any script associated with manipulating the HTML on a CI view right on the view.php file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's eminently reasonable. If you're using jQuery you should probably wrap your manipulation code in a `ready` call.